# fallocate failed: Operation not supported

Tags: 14.04, command-line, dd

When running,

```
fallocate -l 10G /path/to/file
```

I'm returned the following error:

```
fallocate: file: fallocate failed: Operation not supported
```

Creating the file using dd (if=/dev/zero or if=/dev/urandom) works, but if I'm trying to create large files, tens of GBs in size, it takes several hours to complete.

Running Ubuntu 14.04.
Using an ext4 partition, specifying a file-type doesn't appear to alter the outcome.

Working fine on my CentOS6 machines, just not Ubuntu.

Comment: which file system you are using?

Comment: Also update us the type of file you are creating.

Comment: Using ext4, file type doesn't appear to matter. Whether I'm creating a blank file, a .txt, an .img, I receive the same error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If sparse files are ok for you (e.g. you want to create an image in order to populate it with a file system), they are created in no time at all

100GB take 3 milliseconds:

```
# time dd if=/dev/zero of=tmptst.dat bs=1G seek=100 count=0
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 0,00037726 s, 0,0 kB/s

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.002s
```

The resulting file:

```
# ls -lh tmptst.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 100G 2015-01-22 16:39 tmptst.dat
```

Its real size at the moment: 0 Bytes

```
# ls -lsh tmptst.dat
0 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 100G 2015-01-22 16:39 tmptst.dat
```

Comment: It was in regards to creating a dm-crypt/LUKS container, operating under the assumption that creating a container using /dev/urandom would be more secure than creating one with /dev/zero and gradually filling it with data. I've since learned using fallocate wouldn't have solved my problem regardless, as the slow speed was simply a limitation of how fast the pRNG of /dev/urandom works, but I still have no idea why fallocate itself refuses to work. Cheers for the response though, accepted as I imagine after all this time it's the best response I'll get haha.

Comment: I wonder if fallocate can't fallback to do the same thning? That'd make sense to me.

Comment: The `truncate` command does the same `truncate -s 100G tmptst.dat`

Answer (score 5):

I also ran into this problem.

A symbolic link in the directory path seems to be the problem.  try the same command on /tmp and it should work.

I was able to get around the problem by adding a '-x' to the fallocate command.  This forced 'posix mode', and it supposed to take longer.

Even though the filesystem was ext4 the symbolic link was causing the 'not supported on this filesystem' error.  In fact if I went directly to the directory name ( without any symbolic links ), the fallocate() call did work.

A1:  don't have symbolic links anywhere in the full path name of the file you are creating.

A2:  use the '-x', even though it takes longer.

b\375

Answer (score 3):

If you do not care about the content but just need some data,

First do,

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=tmp.txt bs=1M count=1
```

It will create,

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.0M Oct 17 00:30 tmp1.txt.
```

Then, if you like to create a 10M file, use the above generated file for append repeatedly,

```
for i in {1..10}; do dd if=tmp.txt of=tmp1.txt bs=1M oflag=append conv=notrunc; done;
```

Answer (score 0):

The output of `fallocate --help` is:

```
Usage:
 fallocate [options] <filename>

Preallocate space to, or deallocate space from a file.

Options:
 -c, --collapse-range remove a range from the file
 -d, --dig-holes      detect zeroes and replace with holes
 -i, --insert-range   insert a hole at range, shifting existing data
 -l, --length <num>   length for range operations, in bytes
 -n, --keep-size      maintain the apparent size of the file
 -o, --offset <num>   offset for range operations, in bytes
 -p, --punch-hole     replace a range with a hole (implies -n)
 -z, --zero-range     zero and ensure allocation of a range
 -x, --posix          use posix_fallocate(3) instead of fallocate(2)
 -v, --verbose        verbose mode

 -h, --help           display this help
 -V, --version        display version

Arguments:
 <num> arguments may be followed by the suffixes for
   GiB, TiB, PiB, EiB, ZiB, and YiB (the "iB" is optional)
```

Try this command:

```
fallocate -x -l 10G /path/to/file
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).